# How to import MySQL metadata to Apache Atlas Without Storing Hive

Tags: apache-atlas

How to import MySQL metadata to Apache Atlas using sqoop or Spark,
need to show actual RDBMS data types and its column in Apache Atlas
i tried MySQL to hive using sqoop
MySQL to Hive using Spark

I don't want to show Mysql to Hive, its only showing hive datatypes

is there any way to connect MySQL to Apache Atlas like JDBC connection, etc.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your question needs some work so the community can better help you. Take a look at [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and give it another try.